# How to change PyCharm keyboard shortcuts on Mac

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to change the run console command to pressing `SHIFT` and `ENTER`. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#edit) but am unable to understand the actual step to input my personal commands.

I've made it all the way to the screenshot below and need more specific directions to input my personal commands. What do I do next?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is about controlling/setting config for a specific run/script. To change keyboard shortcut/settings go your PyCharm preferences. Select Keymap on the left and in the search bar type "Run". You should see it under Run as the first option. Right click on it and you should see an "Add Keyboar Shortcut" and enter your preferred keyboard shortcut.

Keep in mind that Shift + Enter is already assigned so either change that or try another combination